# Cannot view media queries on desktop, but able to see it when inspecting the page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

I was following a tutorial about media queries. When I open the HTML in Chrome/Firefox, I get a blank page, and nothing displays. When I inspect the page though, the code displays normally and I can see how the media queries work. I tried adjusting the min-width and max-width of the media queries but I still get a blank page in any browser I use. I have posted the original HTML below from the tutorial.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Beginners CSS - Chapter 8</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        margin: 0px;
      }

      main {
        margin: 10px auto;
        width: 600px;
        padding: 30px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        background-color: olive;
        display: block;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
        main {
          background-color: #88a5e0;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        main {
          background-color: red;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        main {
          background-image: url('images/Reeds-in-Wind-Cinemagraph.gif');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover;
          padding-bottom: 400px;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        main {
          background-image: none;
          background-color: #fff;
        }

        h1,
        p {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <h1>Media Queries</h1>
      <p>Media allows you to make your pages to change to fit any device.</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The screen width changes when the developer tool is opened on the right/left dock. So, the elements that you saw perhaps are from the `min-width 800px` media query.

The page when the minimum width is 1000 pixels is not *"blank page and nothing displays"*. You can read from the code below, you're setting the `background-color` to white, hiding the `h1` & `p` and removing the `background-image` when the `min-width: 1000px`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  main {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  h1,
  p {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I completely panicked and did not really study the code the way I should have. Thank you for answering.  I feel embarrassed now that I look at the code and I could have worked it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The page is not blank, according to your code for screens with width more than 1000px you set this styles:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  main {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
  }

  h1, p {display: none;}
}
```

so the h1 and p1 element will not be displayed and the background will be white,
if you resize the window other media queries happen.
Also by Opening your developer tools you are resizing your window.

Comment: It makes sense now that I look at the code and play around with the developer tools how the page was set up through the media  queries.  This goes to show that I have a ton to learn, firstly, making sure I fully understand the code.